# Connecting Lowest Datapoints in Plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm needing to make a fancy plot that draws a line through the lowest x-valued data points. The code below is a working example of similar-looking data to what I'm working with.  Please only use `numpy` and `matplotlib`, and please continue using the `plt.subplots()` method.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

y = np.random.randint(1,20,50)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y, '.')
ax.grid(alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

The above code makes this plot:

[image]

I want a plot that "hugs" the left-most boundary of points, like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a way to determine what your "lowest points" are (i.e. lowest within a certain range), you can try using [numpy.polyfit()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). Here's [a usage example](https://www.statology.org/curve-fitting-python/) from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either define some lower limit under which the left-most boundary sits or you could bin the data on the y-axis and find the point with the smallest x-value in each bin. I'll take the former approach and do the following (using an [interpolator function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)):

```py
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# import the scipy interpolator
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

n = 50
y = np.random.randint(1, 20, n)

# set x-positions (as plotted)
x = np.arange(n)

# set lower boundary on x below which we'll find the "edge"
lowbound = 10

# get the y-values below the lowbound
lowy = y[x < lowbound]

# get indices of unique values below the bound
idx = np.unique(lowy, return_index=True)[1]

# get a linear interpolator between the points
ci = interp1d(y[idx], x[idx], kind="linear")

plt.scatter(x, y)

# plot boundary
yvals = np.linspace(y[idx].min(), y[idx].max(), 100)  # points at which to calculate the interpolant
plt.plot(ci(yvals), yvals, color="r")
```

This gives:

[image]

If your wanted a more curved line you could change `"linear"` in `interp1d` to, e.g., `"cubic"`, but that would not guarantee that it wouldn't include points "inside" the boundary or deviate quite far from an imagined boundary. Using a cubic spline interpolation for the above data gives:

[image]

A way to get a little bit of curvature, but without potentially including points "inside" the boundary, would be to transform into log-space before doing a linear interpolation and the transforming back for plotting, e.g.,:

```py
ci = interp1d(y[idx], np.log10(x[idx] + lowbound), kind="slinear")
plt.plot(10**ci(yvals) - lowbound, yvals, color="r")
```

which gives:

[image]

which is admittedly (in this case) not much different than the original linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your y values are somewhat discrete you can do the following

```
y_unique = np.unique(y)

x_values = np.empty(len(y_unique))

indices = list(range(0, len(y)))

for idx, v in enumerate(y_unique):
    x_values[idx] = np.argmin(indices[y==v])
    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y, '.')
ax.grid(alpha=0.5)

plt.scatter(x=x_values, y=y_unique, color="red")

plt.show()
```

this from mobile and untested